# Save Old and new state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state `newuser` that changes based on the inputs in the input fields, after all, inputs are filled, and the submit button is clicked.

I want to hold the current state of the new user and then as the input fields are filled for the second time I'll have another state to hold previous value of `newuser` and the current value.

```
const [newuser,setnewuser] = useState({'firstname':'','lastname':''});
const [users,setusers] = useState([]); <-- this is expected to hold newuser objects as the submit button is clicked
```

Please, how do I accomplish this, I tried using the spread operator `setusers(...newuser,newuser)`  but it didn't worked.

Comment: How about `setusers([...users, newuser]);`

Comment: It displays just the current state

Comment: Can you show more of your code or a jsFiddle with the minimum code required to reproduce your error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proper solution for this is to save your old state to somewhere like cache or localstorage. For your specific code case, we can use effect to synchronize state

```
const [newuser,setnewuser] = useState({'firstname':'','lastname':''});
const [users,setusers] = useState([]); 
useEffect(() => {
  if(newuser && newuser.firstname && newuser.lastname && !users.includes(newuser)) {
    setusers([...users, newuser])
  }
}, [JSON.stringify(newuser)]);
```

in case you want to use proper solution, I can show a simple solution using cache, you need to install 'memory-cache'

```
import cache from 'memory-cache'
const [newuser, _setnewuser] = useState(cache.get('newuser') || {'firstname':'','lastname':''});
const setnewuser = (user) => {
   _setnewuser(user);
   cache.put('newuser', user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what i actually want to do is to save `newuser` to local storage each time the button is clicked,so my plan was to save all `newuser` to `users` and the push to localstorage

Comment: you can use memory cache or localstorage directly

Comment: Please how do i do that

Comment: I just added a solution using cache. if you want to use localstorage then change cache api to localstorage api instead. The idea is still the same